# Auto-fill from another spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm in need of a way to populate cells in an excel form with specific data from another excel worksheet, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about filling in a template (form) with information from a row-based 'database' sheet, and you're wanting a formula-based solution...

1) On your form, manually enter the "key" piece of information that is usually found in column A of your database.  This could be a code, a unique name, whatever.  Let's say that manual cell was A1.

2) On your form, you would now enter **VLOOKUP** formulas in all the other cells to bring over the matching row information from the database.  So to put the value from column B in your database into cell A5, you could do this in A5:

**=VLOOKUP($A$1, Database!$A:$B, 2, 0)**

To get column C into A10 you could put this in A10:

**=VLOOKUP($A$1, Database!$A:$C, 3, 0)**

...and so on.  When you're done creating your lookup formulas, you can now change the value in A1 and all the other cells will change to information from the database.  If you enter a value in A1 that is not in the database, then the cells would re